# How to authenticate REST API in micro integrator?

Tags: rest, authentication, wso2

I am working with WSO2 and my task is to create REST API which will take data from database and provide it to users.
I did this using Integration studio.

But how can I secure my API using Auth2?
Is there any possibility how can I see my API in WSO2 API manager?

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your service to API Manager and convert the service to a managed API from the API publisher. Please check - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/working-with-service-catalog/

Once you create an API in API Manager you can have OAuth2 for the REST API.

For the complete tutorial please check - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/service-catalog-tutorial/

Update: Alternative method of using WSO2 MI and WSO2 API Manager

1. Extract the car file using the steps in [1].
2. Download the MI runtime from [2].
3. Extract the MI zip and place the car file in MI_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps location.
4. Start the MI server.
5. Download the API Manager from [3] and start it.
6. Create an API in the API Manager. While creating the API, you can provide the MI endpoint as the endpoint of the API in the API Manager.
7. You can deploy and publish the API to start consuming the API.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/integration-development-kickstart/#step-3-build-and-run-the-artifacts

[2] - https://wso2.com/integration/micro-integrator/

[3] - https://wso2.com/api-manager/

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to export project from Integration studio and how to upload it to Micro Integrator. Can you be more specific please? Your tutorials didn't helped much
Thank You

Comment: @BousaCZ Check this video tutorial on creating a managed API https://youtu.be/aa3dKS2E2c0

Comment: I don't understand step 6. What is endpoint of API in the API manager?

Comment: You should give the MI url as the API endpoint in API Manager. The MI url can be http://localhost/8290/sample2

Comment: I have exported API from integration studio into Micro integrator, I can get response from API when I try to call it using Postman, but I still don't see it between services in API manager. Do you know where could be problem?

Comment: Did you configure MI to publish the artifact to API Manager?

Comment: How can I do it please?

Comment: Step 3 configs are used for that - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/service-catalog-tutorial/#step-3-configure-the-micro-integrator

Comment: Thank you, I have changed settings of MI. 
I can see in logs: Executing Service Catalog deployer for CApp : BonnelExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car
But in API manager it is still not visible. 
Do you know where can be problem?

Comment: @Pubci I have been able to publish API from MI into API manager. But I have different problem now. Can you look at this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444623/wso2-invalid-request-line