# WSO2 Invalid request line

Tags: api, rest, wso2

I have REST API which is made based on this tutorial: https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/sending-a-simple-message-to-a-datasource/
I have been able to propagate this API to API manager from micro integrator.
But when I try to call it from API manager, I get response

{
"code": "101500",
"type": "Status report",
"message": "Runtime Error",
"description": "Error in Sender"
}

I have also created Configs and metadata for this API.
But when I try to call my API I get this error at micro integrator.

ERROR {SourceHandler} - HttpException occurred org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid request line: [0x16][0x17][0x18][0x19]├ä[0x1b][0x1c][0x1d]├Ç[0x1f][0x20]csq┬Ż├Ś!┬╝>├Ť┬é├▒[0x2c]├ż!1├ë┬üMc:2U┬ŽV├Ěj6┬ŐaK┬ź[0x40][0x41][0x42]T├Ç$├Ç([0x48]=├Ç&├Ç*[0x4e]k[0x50]j├Ç
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:209)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection$LoggingNHttpMessageParser.parse(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:410)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection$LoggingNHttpMessageParser.parse(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:384)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:262)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:114)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onInputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:82)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onInputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ParseException: Invalid request line: ▬♥♥ ├ä☺  ├Ç♥♥csq┬Ż├Ś!┬╝>├Ť┬é├▒ ├ż!1├ë┬üMc:2U┬ŽV├Ěj6┬ŐaK┬ź∟  T├Ç$├Ç( =├Ç&├Ç* k j├Ç
at org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseRequestLine(BasicLineParser.java:291)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpRequestParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpRequestParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:50)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeadLine(AbstractMessageParser.java:156)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:207)
... 14 more

Comment: Can you directly call the REST API deployed in MI and check whether it's working properly?

Comment: @sanoJ Yes in postman I can call this API and it returns correct values.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error is observed when we send HTTPS requests to the HTTP Listener of the Micro Integrator. The Micro Integrator uses two ports for HTTP (default 8290)and HTTPS(default 8253) connections. If we send an HTTPS request as follows to port 8290 a similar error is observed.

```
curl -X POST "https://localhost:8290/hello/send" -k
```

Therefore could you check the endpoint URLs in the API manager and do the needful?